# How can I initialize an element of an array field?

Tags: java

I am having trouble initializing an array element inside my class. How can I assign an initial value at a specific index of my array field?

```
public class Account{
    int num[] = new int[50];

    // I can't assign a value like this:    
    num[0] = 12345;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what are u asking. Also getter should be named `getStore()` . Use camel naming

Comment: No its not.. I just want to specify the indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the array in the constructor.

Just write:

```
public Account(){
    num[0]=12345;
}
```

inside your class.

The other possibility is to use an initialisation block(but this is less flexible and difficult du document):

```
{
    num[0]=12345;
}
```

(Also in your class)

Comment: How should I return the value?

Comment: @Deku you don't have to. You change the existing value.